# How do you add PostgreSQL Driver as a dependency in Maven?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, maven

I'm trying to develop a Java application with Maven while using Hibernate with a PostgreSQL database for persistence. I don't understand how I'm supposed to connect the PostgreSQL drivers to my application. I  get that you add dependencies in Maven's pom.xml file, which finds jars from a remote repository, but what about other jars?

Comment: PostgreSQL drivers jars are in Maven central repository: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22postgresql%22%20AND%20a%3A%22postgresql%22

Comment: FYI, for a twist on this Question when working in a web app where the JDBC driver needs to be deployed in your web container rather than in your WAR file, see my Question: [Include a library while programming & compiling, but exclude from build, in NetBeans Maven-based project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32087445/642706).

Answer (score 117, accepted):

PostgreSQL drivers jars are included in Central Repository of Maven:

- [List of included versions of PostgreSQL drivers.](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7C%28g%3A%22org.postgresql%22%20OR%20g%3A%22postgresql%22%29%20AND%20a%3A%22postgresql%22)

For PostgreSQL up to 9.1, use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>VERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

or for 9.2+

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>VERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

*(Thanks to @Caspar for the correction)*

Comment: Note that for 9.2 and later, the groupid for the jdbc driver has changed so you need to [search for a groupid of org.postgresql instead of postgresql](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.postgresql%22%20AND%20a%3A%22postgresql%22)

Comment: The latest PostgreSQL JDBC driver supports PostgreSQL Server 7.2+; so, no need for the first (pre-9.2) block. You can find [the latest JDBC drivers from the PostgreSQL site](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html), and your JDK 8 (JDBC 4.2) driver dependency is: 
```<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
</dependency>```

Comment: As of 2017-05, the numbering for the [JDBC driver from jdbc.postgresql.org](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) has been rebooted, currently 42.1.1.

Comment: Even after adding the dependency, I see this error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73381402/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-postgresql-driver-in-terminal

Answer (score 34):

Updating for latest release:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

[Source](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't think this answer is necessary. Consider contributing an edit to the accepted answer if you don't think its `VERSION` is indicative enough to get the latest version.

Comment: It is, but you still have to look for the latest version. Isn't easier if you have everything in here?

Comment: but the version is not latest anymore lol

Answer (score 17):

Depending on your PostgreSQL version you would need to add the postgresql driver to your `pom.xml` file.

For PostgreSQL 9.1 this would be:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <name>Your project name.</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

You can get the code for the dependency (as well as any other dependency) from maven's central repository

If you are using postgresql 9.2+:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <name>Your project name.</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

You can check the latest versions and dependency snippets from:

- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql
- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql

Answer (score 3):

From site PostgreSQL, of date 02/04/2016 (https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html):

> "This is the current version of the driver. Unless you have unusual
>   requirements (running old applications or JVMs), this is the driver
>   you should be using. It supports Postgresql 7.2 or newer and requires
>   a 1.6 or newer JVM. It contains support for SSL and the javax.sql
>   package. If you are using the 1.6 then you should use the JDBC4
>   version. If you are using 1.7 then you should use the JDBC41 version.
>   If you are using 1.8 then you should use the JDBC42 versionIf you are
>   using a java version older than 1.6 then you will need to use a JDBC3
>   version of the driver, which will by necessity not be current"

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What version of `postgresql` it will expect it on runtime?