# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver in Terminal

Tags: java, postgresql, maven

I have seen a LOT of questions on the same topic, but honestly nothing has worked after few hours of debugging here.
I have a java with maven project that calls postgres DB to read and write data. The code builds and runs fine on IntelliJ. I am trying to run it on terminal (so that I can use determine the command that works and use it for my dockerfile).
For compiling:

```
$mvn clean install
```

For running:

```
$java -jar target/posthogdata-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I see the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:383)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:376)
    at luminai.data.PostgresClient.createConnection(PostgresClient.java:19)
    at luminai.data.DataProcessor.main(DataProcessor.java:38)
```

The code is breaking at this line:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

I am confused as to whats the problem at this point. I have the right dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   <version>42.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is my plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                   <manifest>
                      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                      <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                      <mainClass>luminai.data.DataProcessor</mainClass>
                   </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

EDIT:

Commands I have tried:

```
$java -classpath org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.1 -jar target/posthogdata-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

$java -classpath org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.1:* -jar target/posthogdata-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

$java -cp .:org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.1 -jar target/posthogdata-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Why is the postgres jar not part of the classpath automatically, when it is there in the pom and list of External Libraries?

[image]

Here is the structure of my project, I am running the command from >posthogdata
[image]

Comment: The class is not on your classpath.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work:
java -classpath org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.1 -jar target/posthogdata-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: That does not look like correct usage of `-cp` to me. From the [Java spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) usage of -cp or -classpath is as follaws `-cp classpath Specifies a list of directories, JAR files, and ZIP archives to search for class files. Separate class path entries with semicolons (;). Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of the CLASSPATH environment variable.` Do you really have a file named `org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.1`? If so then it is not in the correct location relative to where the command is being run from.

Comment: @sorifiend I have org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.1 jar in the pom and therefore in the External Libraries. I fail to understand why this is not part of the classpath automatically.

Comment: The name of the JAR file is `postgresql-jdbc-42.3.1.jar` so the beginning of the _java_ command should be: `java -cp postgresql-jdbc-42.3.1.jar ` (assuming that the JAR file is in the same directory that you are issuing the command from)

Comment: @Abra I used this like you suggested `java -cp postgresql-jdbc-42.3.1.jar -jar target/posthogdata-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` same error. How do I check the directory of a dependent jar?

Comment: Just search for the file `postgresql-jdbc-42.3.1.jar` on your computer. Or is that file not on your computer?

Comment: Its here: `/Users/meuser/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.3.1`. I am so confused why is java not picking this up? Other dependencies are there as well.

Tried this as well, same error:
`java -cp /Users/meuser/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.3.1/postgresql-42.3.1.jar -jar -jar target/posthogdata-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar `

Comment: If you use `java -jar` the `-cp` option is ignored. This is documented. Your .jar file needs to mention a relative path to the Postgres driver jar in the Class-Path entry in its manifest. NB The `Class.forName()` line hasn't been needed since 2006.

Comment: @user207421 [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) it says you can use -cp with -jar.
I do not have a manifest file for the jar, where does it go in the project structure?

Comment: Okay, so maven would not create the manifest for me so I went ahead and created it using IntelliJ I added the following, but still same error:
`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: postgresql-42.3.1.jar
Main-Class: luminai.data.DataProcessor`

Comment: No it doesn't. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) it *says exactly the opposite*: "when you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored". Re your new manifest, is `postgresql-32.3.1.jar` in the same directory as your JAR file? Because that's what your manifest entry says. If it is say in a `lib` subdirectory the manifest entry for it needs to say so.

Comment: Thanks for quoting! Makes sense, don't know then why it's being used all over StackOveflow. Re the JAR file it's a dependency that is part of my pom.xml. It's definitely not there in any of my project folders, but on my local machine here: `/Users/meuser/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.3.1` How do I get a dependent jar file to a directory in my project?
While my jar file is in the `target` folder

Comment: Because people apparently cannot read, even when they find the correct place, and cite things that don't say what they are claimed to say. I have no idea about Maven but it's doable. In one of my few Maven projects I have `<dependency><groupId>mysql</groupId><artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId><version>8.0.11</version><type>jar</type></dependency>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix. As per the comments and the error itself, the Postgres driver jar was not in the classpath. After certain tries, I changed my pom plugin to include my project's jar in a way that combines all the other dependent jars into it. I guess IntelliJ was doing that for me out of the box.

Changed plugin to:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>luminai.data.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And ran the following commands:

```
$ mvn clean compile assembly:single
$ java -jar target/posthogdata-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```